# Log into vimeo using xAuth

Tags: ios, api, oauth, vimeo, xauth

I try to login within my app to vimeo to upload videos, the App I created on vimeo is approved.

> Upload Access
>
> Approved for the following accounts: Your account

I use AFNetworking and AFOAuth1Client (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth1Client) but also tried AFXAuthClient (https://github.com/romaonthego/AFXAuthClient).

using AFOAuth1Client with the following code:

```
self.vimeoClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vimeoBaseUrl]
                                                       key:@"ClientIDHere"
                                                    secret:@"SecretHere"];
[self.vimeoClient postPath:@"/oauth/access_token"
                parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"client_auth",@"x_auth_mode",@"myEmail",@"x_auth_username",@"myPwd",@"x_auth_password",@"write",@"x_auth_permission", nil]
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"...");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@":%@", error.description);
}];
```

I get this error:

> VimeoTest[49559:c07] :Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011
>   "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x75622d0
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=401 Unauthorized - Invalid signature -
>   The oauth_signature passed was not valid.,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

using AFXAuthClient with the following code:

```
//update begin
AFXAuthToken *token = [[AFXAuthToken alloc] initWithKey:@"Access token from vimeo" secret:@"Access token secret"];
[self.vimeoXClient setToken:token];
//update end

self.vimeoXClient = [[AFXAuthClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vimeoBaseUrl] 
key:@"ClientIDHere" 
secret:@"SecretHere"];
[self.vimeoXClient authorizeUsingXAuthWithAccessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token"
                                             accessMethod:@"POST"
                                                 username: @"myEmail"
                                                 password: @"myPwd"
                                                  success:^(AFXAuthToken *accessToken) {
                                                      NSLog(@"...");
                                                  }
                                                  failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"error: %@", error.description);

                                                  }];
```

I get this Error:

> 2013-07-16 20:18:27.819 VimeoTest[49680:c07] error: Error
>   Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7223e80
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=400 Bad Request - Missing required
>   parameter - A required parameter was missing: oauth_token.,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

error after updating code (setting the token):

> 2013-07-16 21:20:14.060 VimeoTest[52437:c07] error: Error
>   Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x8b245a0
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=401 Unauthorized - Permission Denied -
>   The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired.,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

anyone has any Idea what I am doing wrong?

--- UPDATE ---

using Runscope I send the following parameters

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="63129149524659229601374074093", oauth_timestamp="1374074093", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="MYCONSUMERKEYHERE", oauth_token="MYAPPTOKENHERE", oauth_callback="None", oauth_verifier="None", oauth_signature="lW%2BQYzwCcaDzSgoZUtvpSgLRSF4%3D"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Host: vimeo-com-bbmyq45awg44.runscope.net
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
X-Forwarded-For: 54.236.210.241
X-Forwarded-Protocol: https
X-Forwarded-Ssl: on
X-Real-Ip: 54.236.210.241
X_auth_mode: client_auth
X_auth_password: MYPWDHERE
X_auth_permission: write
X_auth_username: MYUSERNAMEHERE
```

I still get the same response

```
HEADERS

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Length: 104
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 15:14:53 GMT
Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 03:14:53 GMT
Runscope-Message-Id: 7bd9d07d-d043-4486-9a19-c3572997d3e4
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: on
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14
BODY view raw

401 Unauthorized - Permission Denied - The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired.
```

I am really not sure if I miss some params. Is the oauth_verifier or oauth_callback needed?
In my vimeo App setup I got the following:

> Your Callback URL (edit)  vimeoTest://success

Comment: If you are successfully receiving the message "The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired" then I assume you are sending your request properly. 

You can validate that all the headers and parameters are set successfully by using [Runscope](http://runscope.com).

If all of the proper headers are being sent, Vimeo has the ability to verify the token you are using. You can contacting them at via their [help page](https://vimeo.com/help/contact).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I had to manually add the oauth_callback parameter to the request. If you have a desktop app and won't be using it, set it to oob.